# Multi-dimensional tensor multiplication: tensor shape conformation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I've been studying neural networks lately, where typically we work with higher order tensors beyond 2D and do tensor multiplication.

In traditional matrix-matrix multiplication $A\times B$, we just have to make sure the number of columns of $A$ aligns with the number of rows of $B$, but I'm wondering how this works for higher order tensors? i.e., which dimensions do we have to make sure matches between the two tensors $A$ and $B$?

Comment: All tensors I have seen so far have the same number of possible indices in all directions. In that sense matrix multiplication is more general.

Comment: @KurtG. Could you clarify what you mean by "same number of possible indices in all directions?" i.e., all dimensions are the same size for the tensor?

Comment: For example in special and general relativity we write tensors as ${T^{\alpha\beta}}_\gamma$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ always run from $0$ to $3$.